# Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver Slow on initial launch

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, launching

Initial launching of the Chrome driver is taking 35 seconds on average everything works fine just can't speed up the launch time. Using Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver Version 2.35, NuGet by Jsakamoto. Additional nuget packages are Selenium.support 3.9.1 and selenium.webdriver 3.9.1 by Selenium Committers. How can I speed up the initial launching of the ChromeDriver?

```
  [TestMethod, TestCategory("DriverSpeed"), TestCategory("GUI")]
        public void SpeedingUpOption()
        {
            Stopwatch time = new Stopwatch();
            time.Start();
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

            // Tried many options nothing helped

            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
            time.Stop();
            IWebElement searchBox = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
            searchBox.SendKeys("ChromeDriver Slow");
            driver.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Is your machine slow in general? Is it slow to boot Chrome manually and browse? Are you low on RAM? Do you have lots of other applications open? Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: The machine isn't slow. Manual boot is fast 1-2 seconds. Not low on ram I tried checking if this was a machine error and ran it on other machines,  the outcome was same. I tried rebooting and making sure other applications weren't getting in the way. Seemed to be not  a machine error.